# InjectionUtils can not access a member of class DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone

Tags: java, cxf, jodatime

I am trying to send a post request with cxf implementation. But I am getting

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils can not access a member of class org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone with modifiers "public"

My method interface is :

```
@GET
@Path("history")
HistoryResult getHistory(@Valid @QueryParam("") HistoryParameters historyParameters)
```

HistoryParameters has two joda time LocalDate :
    public class HistoryParameters {

```
    @NotNull
    @QueryParam("historyType")
    private HistoryType historyType;

    @FieldDescription(title = "Archive from date", value = "Archive from date")
    @QueryParam("archiveFromDate")
    private LocalDate archiveFromDate;

    @FieldDescription(title = "Archive to date", value = "Archive to date")
    @QueryParam("archiveToDate")
    private LocalDate archiveToDate;

    public HistoryParameters() {

    }
    ...
}
```

Here the stacktrace :

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils can not access a member of class org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone with modifiers "public"
>       at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:109)
>       at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:261)
>       at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:253)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.extractFromMethod(InjectionUtils.java:324)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.extractFromMethod(InjectionUtils.java:316)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.fillInValuesFromBean(InjectionUtils.java:1147)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.fillInValuesFromBean(InjectionUtils.java:1174)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.fillInValuesFromBean(InjectionUtils.java:1174)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.fillInValuesFromBean(InjectionUtils.java:1174)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.fillInValuesFromBean(InjectionUtils.java:1174)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.fillInValuesFromBean(InjectionUtils.java:1174)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.fillInValuesFromBean(InjectionUtils.java:1174)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.fillInValuesFromBean(InjectionUtils.java:1174)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.extractValuesFromBean(InjectionUtils.java:1109)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.addMatrixQueryParamsToBuilder(AbstractClient.java:677)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.handleQueries(ClientProxyImpl.java:455)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:178)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.getHistoryEntries(Unknown Source)

Comment: `DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone` seems to be a private inner class and thus the message does make sense. I don't know both CXF and JodaTime very well but I'd assume you need some custom (maybe provided by JodaTime) conversion code. Did you debug to see what CXF tries to convert and from which source value?

Comment: I think my problem is before converting an instance of LocalDate. My problem appears when cxf introspect all QueryParam to get a value to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue instead of using @QueryParam("") which introspect all attributes, I used @BeanParam annotation but be careful @QueryParam inside the pojo (HistoryParameters in my example) have to be set on setter.